# Cross Origin Domain Problem on Apex Rest Method

Tags: visualforce, rest, cross-domain

I have been using custom rest method for long time for file uploading and it was working properly. however last week , it started to throw error where the request is send.
I have rest method in class to upload files in content.

Here is my rest method that is invoked on http post.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/attach')
global with sharing class RestContentUploader

{

@HttpPost
global static String attach(){

     RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
     RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
     //res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     //res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://mds.na15.visual.force.com');
     res.statusCode =200;
     String upload_pid,upload_filename,upload_recordtype,upload_libraryId,upload_docId,specialties,subspecialties,fileIdentity,fileSubId,date_value;
     Boolean is_Client_Document=true;
     Boolean is_hidden;
     //Request Header parameters;
     upload_pid = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('upload_pid'));
     upload_filename = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('upload_filename'));
     upload_recordtype = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('upload_recordtype'));
     upload_libraryId = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('upload_libraryId'));
     upload_docId = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('upload_docId'));
     specialties = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('specialties'));
     subspecialties = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('subspecialties'));
     fileIdentity = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('fileIdentity'));
     fileSubId = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('fileSubId'));
     date_value = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('date_value'));
     is_hidden = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('ishidden'))=='true' ? true : false ; 
     is_Client_Document = RestContentUploader.decodeURLParam(req.headers.get('isclient'))=='true' ? true :false;


    Blob bin= req.requestBody;

    if( String.isBlank(upload_pid)|| String.isBlank(upload_filename)|| String.isBlank(upload_recordtype) || String.isBlank(upload_libraryId)){
        res.statusCode = 400;
        return 'missing upload headers';
    }
    //Removed the logic due to wrong versioning 01/08/2014
    // if(upload_docId== '' || upload_docId== null)

      try
      {
        ContentVersion att = new ContentVersion (
            Authorization__c = upload_pid,
            VersionData= bin,
            PathOnClient= upload_filename,
            Title= upload_filename,
            FirstPublishLocationId=upload_libraryId,
            RecordTypeId=upload_recordtype,
            Specialties__c= specialties,
            FileSubIdentity__c=fileSubId,
            FileIdentity__c=fileIdentity,
            Subspecialties__c=subspecialties,
            DateSpecifier__c=(String.isEmpty(date_value) ? null :Date.parse(date_value)),
            Client_Document__c=is_Client_Document,
            IsHidden__c=is_hidden
        );
        system.debug('ContentVersion Initialize====>'+att);

        insert att;

        //Return the new attachment Id
        res.addHeader('fileName', att.Title);
        return att.Id;
      }
      catch(exception xx)
      {
        system.debug('***RESPONSE XX***'+res);
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.addHeader('fileName', upload_filename);

        system.debug('***RESPONSE XX22***'+res);
        return xx.getMessage();
      } 


} 
public static string decodeURLParam(string param){
    return String.isBlank(param) ? null : EncodingUtil.urlDecode(param,'UTF-8');
}


}
```

Im using jquery file upload library and here is the piece of script codes which request is sent.

```
 $('#'+fileInputId).fileupload('send',{
                       files:data.files,
                       beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('SalesforceProxy-Endpoint',{!fileInputHtmlId}_restUrl);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Agent', 'salesforce-toolkit-rest-javascript/v36.0');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('upload_filename',fileName);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('upload_pid','{!parentId}');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('upload_libraryId','{!libraryId}');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('upload_docId','{!contentDocumentId}');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('upload_recordtype','{!recordTypeId}');
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('isclient',{!isClient});
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('ishidden',document.getElementById('{!fileInputHtmlId}_'+removeWhiteSpace(removeDots(fileName))+'_check').checked);
                        }
                 });//fileUpload
```

I have tried many things, i have added origin domain in CORS, i have manipulated response headers as adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, they all do not work.

Here is my CORS list.

[image]

And here is the error that im getting on client side!!

[image]

Are there anyone who is having same issue ? Any suggestion or workaround would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce is aware of the issue, and is trying to determine the root cause. Basically, the Salesforce AJAX proxy is dropping the Authentication header, which causes the API to return a 401 Not Authorized error. You should log a case with support so they can notify you of the problem once it is resolved and keep track of how many customers are affected.

---

Edit #1:

Salesforce is pushing out a hot fix this weekend for the problem. Everything should be just fine by Monday morning. If you continue to experience problems, please feel free to let us know.

---

Edit #2:

We now also have a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000185IjQAI) logged for this.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks, that made me feel better...